# Designation in the personal data

Tags: cv

What does the term "Designation" mean, in the fulfillment of the personal Data in a work application or a CV? it said the following!!
""Presenter(s) identifying information as follows:
Full name:
Age:,
Designation:,
Current Status/ Position:,
Department & University:,
Address:,
Mobile:,""

Comment: No idea.  Can you give more context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, it can mean one of two things:

- Your title. For example, Dr., Rev., Arch., Atty., Engr., etc.
- Your job title. For example, Head of Gastrointestinal Surgery, Parish Priest, Associate Professor of Global Health, etc.

It really depends on the place in the application in which the information is being sought and for what use.

Anyway, good luck!